# Android arraylist into Textview error

Tags: java, android, arraylist, textview

I tried to set value in `TextView` using my array logic.

**Problem**:

Instead of my actual value it might set address of string in
textview. I'm guessing this issue is simple, possibly not specifying `.toString()`?

Value that is being outputted:

```
com.android.carModel.Car@eacea24f
```

My code:

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    val = carDAO.carOutput(carId);
    textbx.setText("");
    for (Car details : val){
        builder.append(details + "\n");
    }
    textbx.setText(builder.toString());
```

Comment: Try doing details.getName() or what you have in model class like this
  builder.append(details.getName()  + "\n");

Comment: can you show your Car class

Comment: you need to override toString in the class Car

Comment: That was it.  I forgot to access the Getter method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually append someObjectClassname@hashcodenumber i.e com.android.carModel.Car@eacea24f in your case to stringBuilder. To get the desired output you need to do something like this.

```
`builder.append(details.getName() /*or anything*/ + "\n")`
```

Comment: Doing this or overriding the `toString` method should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the `Car` class? If so, add this method:

```
public String toString() {
    return carName;
}
```

Replace `carName` with whatever you want to display. This `toString()` method is part of the `Object` class that all classes extend, and when overridden, it will change what something like a List will display.